# android - how to create this draggable menu

Tags: android, material-design

I have 3 main actions on my app. So I want a draggable icon that the user drag on direction of the desired action. Example:

[image: example]

I've found some circular menu libraries on github, but no one seems to have the option to drag the central icon. How can I create this? Maybe a free draggable button with colision test to detect desired action?